# Syncing Incognito tabs

Tags: google-chrome

Does signing into Google Chrome sync Incognito tabs? Or are they exempt?

I've had lots of trouble getting tab syncing working at all (phone or computer will at times randomly fail to see the other's tabs), and when it does, I've yet to see incognito tabs synced.

Comment: Syncing tabs from incognito mode would kind of go against the idea of incognito mode in the first place, no?

Comment: @AlEverett - Probably, I was just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incognito tabs don't get sync'd.